# Login error for admin SQL Server during terraform plan

Tags: terraform, azure-sql-server

I'm building an Azure infrastructure with terraform. I need to create a specific user of the DB for each DB in the server. To create the users I use the provider "betr-io / mssql", to create the users I use the following script:

```
resource "mssql_login" "sql_login" {
  server {
    host = "${var.sql_server_name}.database.windows.net"
    # host = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.fully_qualified_domain_name
    login {
      username = var.sql_admin_user
      password = var.sql_admin_psw
    }
  }
  login_name = var.sql_dbuser_username
  password   = var.sql_dbuser_password
  depends_on    = [azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver, azurerm_mssql_database.sqldb]
}

resource "mssql_user" "sql_user" {
  server {
    host = "${var.sql_server_name}.database.windows.net"
    # host = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.fully_qualified_domain_name
    login {
      username = var.sql_admin_user
      password = var.sql_admin_psw
    }
  }
  username = var.sql_dbuser_username
  password = var.sql_dbuser_password
  database = var.sql_db_name
  roles    = var.sql_dbuser_roles
  depends_on  = [azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver, azurerm_mssql_database.sqldb, mssql_login.sql_login]
}
```

What the terraform plan gives me is this error

> Error: unable to read user [sqldb-dev].[dbuser]: login error: mssql: Login failed for user 'usr-admin'.
>
> with mssql_user.sql_user,
> on main.tf line 346, in resource "mssql_user" "sql_user":
> 346: resource "mssql_user" "sql_user" {

I can't understand the problem where it might come from, has anyone had a similar experience?

For completeness of information, the databases are hosted in an elastic pool instance.

Comment: Question where have that sql_admin_user been created? on sql server? I got similar output when trying to log in using service account (user/password) from AD group that was assigned as Admin for that Azure SQL Server. For me only `sqlcmd -G -U user -P pass` worked which obviously had to be wrap into `null_resource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found is to destroy the users and recreate them with the databases.
Unfortunately I haven't found a way to add devops to the sql server whitelist.